# Create ExpandoObject using Datatable

Tags: c#, dynamic, reflection, properties

I am new to C# and gone through lot of questions in Stackoverflow.com and didn't find the solution for my requirement. So finally posting here.

My requirement is to create the dynamic properties from datatable column names and set the values to dynamic properties from datatable. and finally bind the data to gridview.

So I decided to follow below steps to achieve this functionality( kindly Correct me If I am wrong)

my datatable contains 26 rows and 10 columns of data

1. Create a Class A
2. Add dynamic properties to A from datatable(column names)
3. Set values to properties of A
4. Make class A to List of A
5. Bind List of A to GridView

I have done the below steps

1.

```
[Serializable]
public class A
{   
  public A() 
  {   
  }  
}
```

2 & 3.

```
DataTable dt = getData();

dynamic expando = new ExpandoObject();

foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{
   foreach (DataColumn col in dt.Columns)
   {
     var expandoDict = expando as IDictionary<String, Object>;

     if (expandoDict.ContainsKey(col.ToString()))
       expandoDict[col.ToString()] = row[col.ColumnName].ToString();
     else
       expandoDict.Add(col.ToString(), row[col.ColumnName].ToString());
   }
}
```

After executing the above for loop, "expando" object contains only last row of datatable.

Can you please help me how to fix the steps 2 to 5.

Comment: You basically have a dictionary. Each loop, you are finding the name of the column, and using that as the key. You then re-assign the value at that key to be the value at that column in that row. It looks to me like what you really want is a List of ExpandoObject instead of a single one. Each inner loop should add another ExpandoObject to that list instead of reassigning the values on the same object.

Answer (score 8):

From what I understand, this code may be more what you are looking for. This should get the data into the expandoList for you. You will then need to handle the binding to the GridView.

```
DataTable dt = getData();

List<dynamic> expandoList = new List<dynamic>();

foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{
    //create a new ExpandoObject() at each row
    var expandoDict = new ExpandoObject() as IDictionary<String, Object>;
    foreach (DataColumn col in dt.Columns)
    {
        //put every column of this row into the new dictionary
        expandoDict.Add(col.ToString(), row[col.ColumnName].ToString());
    }

    //add this "row" to the list
    expandoList.Add(expandoDict);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much user1304444. It helped. I will figure out how to bind List<dynamic> to gridview.

Comment: Actually I am binding all the columns in code behind code. Turned off the AutoGenerateColumns="false". While binding the expandoList, the  gridview not able to find the column name under List<Dictionary<Key, Value>>. Any clues.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an extension method that would convert your datatable to list of Dynamic objects:

```
public static class DataTableExtension
{
    public static IEnumerable<dynamic> AsDynamicEnumerable(this DataTable table)
    {
        // Validate argument here..

        return table.AsEnumerable().Select(row => new DynamicRow(row));
    }

    private sealed class DynamicRow : DynamicObject
    {
        private readonly DataRow _row;

        internal DynamicRow(DataRow row) { _row = row; }
        public override bool TryGetMember(GetMemberBinder binder, out object result)
        {
            var retVal = _row.Table.Columns.Contains(binder.Name);
            result = retVal ? _row[binder.Name] : null;
            return retVal;
        }
    }
}
```

Usage: `IEnumerable<dynamic> result = getData().AsEnumerable();`

Comment: I am not able to build this statement. IEnumerable<dynamic> = dt.AsEnumerable(); getting 'only assignment call increment decrement await and new object expressions can be used as a statement'

Comment: I missed to define the variable name. See updated answer.

Comment: Got it. Thank you